# .htaccess Forcing HTTPS and in some cases www. but excluding specific subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are using cPanel for some websites and we use the following .htaccess rules and for the most part they work perfectly but they have a few issues...

```
# Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

With the rule below, if we visit non-www links they correctly get switched to www. links which is good

```
# Force HTTPS & WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The problem with this `Force HTTPS & WWW` rule is when we come to subdomains...

1. If we visit `staging.website.com` it incorrectly gets rewritten to `www.staging.website.com`. Sure a condition like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\. [NC]` could be used but that means every subdomain would need one setup.
2. Another issue with adding that condition is if we visit staging.website.com it won't be forced to use https...
3. In a more complex setup we have a cPanel account where 3 websites are `https://` and one is `https://www.` and for that particular cPanel account I don't know how I can modify these .htaccess rules to work for both scenarios...

#1 and #2 are most noticeable when it comes to `ipv6.website.com`

## Rule Test for Forcing **`httPs & WWW**

- `https://website.com` --> `https://www.website.com`
- `http://website.com` --> `https://www.website.com`
- `https://www.website.com` --> `https://www.website.com`
- `http://www.website.com` --> `https://www.website.com`
- `https://ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `http://ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `https://www.ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `http://www.ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `https://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `http://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `http://www.randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `https://ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `http://ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `https://www.ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `http://www.ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`

## Rule Test for Forcing **`httPs & Non-WWW**

- `https://website.com` --> `https://website.com`
- `http://website.com` --> `https://website.com`
- `https://www.website.com` --> `https://website.com`
- `http://www.website.com` --> `https://website.com`
- `https://ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `http://ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `https://www.ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `http://www.ipv6.website.com` --> `https://ipv6.website.com`
- `https://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `http://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `https://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `http://randomsubdomain.website.com` --> `https://www.randomsubdomain.website.com`
- `https://ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `http://ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `https://www.ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`
- `http://www.ftp.website.com` --> `http://ftp.website.com`

Comment: In your question please add websites that need both `https` and `www` then websites that need only `https`

Comment: @anubhava I don't follow?

Comment: @anubhava I'm looking to fix the 3 issues listed at the bottom relating to subdomains. #1 is the main issue and I don't know how exactly i can make that clearer...

Comment: So problem is that `www` gets added before subdomains. Now please tell what are websites that need `www` in addition to main domain which is `website.com`?  (This is what I asked in my original comment)

Comment: @anubhava correct. It would only be the main domain that gets the `www.` added to it. All subdomains should be exempt from having `www.` automatically appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to have 2 separate redirect rules here:

1. For root domain to add `www` and `https://`
2. For sub domains to add `https://` only

You can have your .htaccess as this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # enforce http:// and non-www for ftp domain:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(ftp\..+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ftp\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Force HTTPS & WWW for any subdomain not in list
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(?:^|\.)(?:ipv6|mail|mobile|staging|cpanel)\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    # Force HTTPS & non-WWW for listed sub domains
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?:ipv6|maill|mobile|staging|cpanel)\..+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The problem with that is having to specify the domain; you can see in my original ones that it's dynamic and I don't have to specify and that's what I am trying to do with it.

Comment: You may see several of my answers for this kind of problem and I always advocate not specifying any host name. In this case it became necessary because of the nature of your problem and if you look closely we are not specifying each and every subdomain. Only root domain name is used in both rules.

Comment: What about targeting specific subdomains? For example targeting `ipv6.website.com` or `ftp.website.com` or `mobile.website.com` or `staging.website.com` Can we target the `ipv6` part of the domain and wildcard the rest of the domain?

Comment: Of course specific subdomains can be targeted. That's what I asked in my comments below the question couple of times but didn't get any clear answers

Comment: that works pretty good, the only issue with it is that the `ftp` subdomain should never have https because you can't connect to FTP over SNI.

Comment: Hmm, something is going odd with it. It clashes with pseudo document roots and causes a 404 page not found error.

See https://i.imgur.com/yddQdN1.png for an example of one at the bottom.

You can see i've cloned your code to provide a HTTPS + WWW and also a HTTPS + non-WWW for the main domain / domains that aren't listed.

Comment: I'm confused, I'm not using all 4 on each site, just 2 per site. Remember some sites want https + www, some just want https as shown https://i.imgur.com/q462CGf.png (Of course as mentioned before the `example.website.com` would be nice if it didn't have `www` but we don't want to have to define the website name in these rules.). So I'm pasting all 4 rule sets but only uncommeting one group. I've updated the Original post to give you some example URLs. Maybe i've explained something poorly.

Comment: ok try my updated rules after clearing your browser cache. No need to add any other redirect rule now. Just add your subdomains in alternation list of rules #3 and #4